# C++ Обязательно ли использовать при создании цикла скобки?

Tags: c#, c++, c

по моему очень важно, без скобках цикл не бывает.

Comment: есть варианты    1)Да и только фигурные скобки  2)Да и только квадратные скобки   3)Да и только круглые скобки  4)Нет не обязательно, если телом цикла является одна строка

Comment: А ещё есть вареант: не знаю рускава - палучаю кол па праграмируванею.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. Например, вы можете создать бесконечный цикл при помощи одного лишь `goto`.

```
loop:
    goto loop;
```

Comment: Автор в комментарии к вопросу (`есть варианты 1)Да и только фигурные скобки 2)Да и только квадратные скобки 3)Да и только круглые скобки 4)Нет не обязательно, если телом цикла является одна строка`) указал, что ему надо выбрать один из четырёх вариантов ответа на тестовый вопрос (а не *да/нет*). И `goto` в этот список не входит.

Comment: @Arhad: Ну, в такой вот формулировке вопрос является дампом тестового задания, и требует ответа в виде выбранного пункта. И из ответа, кстати, следует, что _ни один_ из вариантов не правильный.

Comment: @Arhad: И вопросу в _такой_ формулировке (выберите один из пунктов) я бы поставил минус. Вы ведь не первый день на ru.SO и знаете, что тут у нас нет пункта бесплатной помощи учащимся.

Comment: `и знаете, что тут у нас нет пункта бесплатной помощи учащимся` — знаю, потому и обратил внимание на бесполезность и ответа для справшивающего, и текущей версии вопроса для сообщества.

Comment: @Arhad: Вопрос без комментария гольфообразен (накладывает на код необычное ограничение) и более-менее соответствует и тематике, и сложившейся традиции.